# Expectation of uniformly distributed random variables on unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, spheres

Random vector $X = ( X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) $ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Find $M_2 =E[X_1^2], M_4= E[X_1^4]$

In this case, author asks to find out second and fourth moments of random variable X.

**Author's Solution:**
Since $X_i$ are identically distributed and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i =1. $ It readily follows that $M_2= \displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$

For $M_4$, first note that by squaring $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i =1 $ and taking expectation we obtain $$n M_4 + n(n-1)V_{12}=1 \tag {1}\label{(1)}$$
where $V_{12}=E\left[X_1^2X_2^2\right]$.

Thus, to complete the solution, we need another relation between $M_4$ and $V_{12}$.

To this end, note that $(X_1, X_2)$ and $\left(\displaystyle\frac{X_1 + X_2}{\sqrt{2}}, \displaystyle\frac{X_1-X_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ are identically distributed. Hence $E\left[\displaystyle\frac{(X_1 +X_2)^2 (X_1 -X_2)^2}{4}\right] = E\left[X_1^2X_2^2\right]$ which after expanding gives $M_4 = 3V_{12}$

Combined with \eqref{(1)}, this yields $M_4= \displaystyle\frac{3}{n(n+2)}$

**Author's remark(1)**

A common way to generate uniform distribution on the sphere is to take $X_i=\displaystyle\frac{Z_i}{\sqrt{Z_1^2 +Z_2^2 +\dots, +Z_n^2}}$, where $Z_i$ are independent standard Normal random variables.

---

**My thoughts**

We know $V_{12}=E[X_1^2X_2^2]= E\left[\displaystyle\frac{X_1^4 -2X_1^2X_2^2 +X_2^4}{4}\right]$

If we substitute the aforesaid value of $V_{12}$ in \eqref{(1)}
we get $$nE[X_1^4] + n^2\frac{E[X_1^4]}{4}- 2\cdot n^2\frac{E[X_1^2X_2^2]}{4} + n^2\frac{E[X_2^4]}{4} -n\frac{E[X_1^4]}{4} + 2\cdot n \frac{[X_1^2X_2^2]}{4}  - n\frac{E[X_2^4]}{4}=1$$

Now how to proceed further?

Note: I performed further computations but  I didn't get $E[X_1^4]=3V_{12}$. That's why I stuck at this step.

---

**New thoughts** (after reopening of the post and publication of the accepted answer):

Combined with \eqref{(1)}, $M_4 = 3V_{12}$ we get  $M_4= \displaystyle\frac{3}{n(n+2)}$

**Working:**

We know $V_{12}=E[X_1^2X_2^2]= E\left[\displaystyle\frac{X_1^4 -2X_1^2X_2^2 +X_2^4}{4}\right]= \displaystyle\frac{M_4}{3}$

If we substitute $V_{12}=E\left[\displaystyle\frac{X_1^4 -2X_1^2X_2^2 +X_2^4}{4}\right]$ in \eqref{(1)}
we get $$nE[X_1^4] +\frac{n(n-1)}4\left(E(X_1^4)-2E(X_1^2X_2^2)+E(X_2^4)\right)=1.$$

If you solve for $M_4= E[X_1^4]$ we get $$\left[ E[X_1^4] - E[X_1^2X_2^2]\right] =\displaystyle\frac{2}{n(n+2)}$$. Substituting $V_{12}=\displaystyle\frac{M_4}{3}$ we get, $M_4=\displaystyle\frac{3}{n(n+2)}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Your post needs more focus, and a report of your attempts.

Comment: Hi! As the other comments imply, your question would benefit from a bit more precision as to what part of the author's argument you're having trouble with. Since it's a fair amount of work to explain literally each part of it, it really helps to know which parts make sense to you, and which don't. It's best if you edit your post to include this context. ¶ Some hints that *might* help you (it's unclear, after all): The "other relation between $M_4$ and $V_{12}$" is basically a rotation by $45$ degrees, which leaves the distribution unchanged (remark (1)). The rest is mostly just algebra.

Comment: @BrianTung, How to get $M_4=3V_{12}$ by substituting $E\left[ \displaystyle\frac{(X_1^2 +X_2^2) (X_1^1 -X_2^2)}{4}\right] = E[X_1^2X_2^2]$ in the equation tagged (1)?

Comment: Expand the left-hand expression, and then apply linearity of expectation. (That is, $E(aX+bY) = aE(X)+bE(Y)$, etc.)

Comment: Please roll back: you shouldn't modify your post after it got an answer which you accepted. Moreover, though correct, your proof is overcomplicated, compared to the author's one, Do you need me to expand my answer to explain the latter in greater detail?

Comment: (One day later) Since you didn't answer my comment, and modified your post again, I took the liberty to rollback as required, but preserved your recent edits in a new paragraph at the end. All these "new thoughts" are wrong. I shall comment them later in my answer below (unless you understand before, and delete them), and add the proposed (and seemingly needed) explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding $E\left[\displaystyle\frac{(X_1 +X_2)^2 (X_1 -X_2)^2}{4}\right] = E\left[X_1^2X_2^2\right]$ and using that $E[X_2^4]=E[X_1^4]=M_4$ and $E\left[X_1^2X_2^2\right]=V_{12}$ gives *immediately* $V_{12}=\frac{M_4}3$. It is *this* expression of $V_{12}$ which the author substitued in $n M_4 + n(n-1)V_{12}=1$.

Edit 5 days later to expand this answer, hopefully letting you understand why you (old and new) thoughts were not adequate:

- You began your "Workings" with "We know $V_{12}=[\dots=\dots]= \displaystyle\frac{M_4}{3}$". No, we don't know it yet.
- You insisted on *substituting* $$V_{12}=E\left[\displaystyle\frac{X_1^4 -2X_1^2X_2^2 +X_2^4}{4}\right]\tag {2}\label{(2)}$$
  in $$n M_4 + n(n-1)V_{12}=1 \tag1\label{(1bis)}$$
  This is overcomplicating things and the author's method was much simpler: he first *expanded* \eqref{(2)} as follows:
  $$V_{12}=\frac{M_4-2V_{12}+M_4}4,$$
  which simplifies to $V_{12}=\frac{M_4}3$, and then substituted *this* (not \eqref{(2)}) in \eqref{(1bis)}, resulting in
  $$n M_4 + n(n-1)\frac{M_4}3=1$$
  i.e. $M_4=\frac3{n(n+2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at a similar problem very recently. Write the vector in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), where your $X_1$ corresponds to $x_1 = \cos\varphi_1$ in the notation of Wikipedia. Then integrate
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{[0,\pi]^{n-2}}\cos^k\varphi_1\sin^{n-2}\varphi_1\ldots\sin\varphi_{n-2}\mathrm d \varphi,$$
to get the $k$th moment. The integral with respect to the components $\varphi_i$ for $i > 1$ equates to the surface area of the sphere of dimension $n-2$. Then you're left with the integral with respect to $\varphi_1$.

Comment: While this may be true (I haven't checked, but I'll stipulate to it for now), I'm not sure how this helps OP's confusion with the author's approach...